# What mechanism in python (on linux) can I use to allow unrelated processes communicate in an async persistent fashion?

Tags: python, linux, asynchronous, fifo

Looking for a solution using python.

I have a start process (kicked off from a webpage) that will spawn a worker process and respond back to the webpage that the worker process has started.  The worker process will continue to do its job until it completed. The worker process will output it's current running status as it completes various steps. At the same time a reader process is kicked off (a long poll from the webpage). The reader would then read the worker's status updates (if any) and return them to the webpage. This long poll would continue to check the worker process status until all tasks are completed.

I attempted to use named pipes (fifo), but due to their nature, "The FIFO must be  opened  on  both  ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed.  Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also." Also, if I open the fifo os.O_RDWR the worker appears to write to the pipe, but since nothing is on the other end (to read), the data just goes to the bit bucket. So the reader would not see any updates. I was hoping it would sit in the pipe until it was read, but that is not the case.

I want to avoid any blocking of the worker or the reader.  Just have the worker dump out an update and move on to its next step, repeat until it is done.  The reader should check for any updates left by the worker and read them.  If there are no current updates, it should just return, where another poll could then be started by the webpage.

Hopefully this makes sense. Is there a better way that I am not thinking of?

Comment: Are both the parent and worker processes the same python code? If so, this sounds like a case for the multiprocessing stdlib module's Pipe or Queue.

Comment: Presumably you have a web application already that will receive the request and fire off the process.  The browser app can make periodic AJAX requests to fetch the status, and your web app can read a simple status file, updated by the external process, and return the status.  It's not that hard.

Comment: This seems exactly the use case for the `multiprocessing` module and the `Queue` class it defines.

Comment: @tonymke No the parent would spawn the worker and then return back to the web app that the process has been started and that it should now start polling for status.

Comment: @TimRoberts I was hoping to avoid a file (with locking etc.) as there could be multiple instances. But if that is the best way, then so be it.  I was just hoping pipes (or some other IPC) would do the  trick.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Will a queue be persistent as the various processes close or have not been  started yet?

Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: Can't say for sure unless actual code is shown. I think the most reasonable way to achieve what you want is to spawn a process and make that one spawn both the worker and the reader (e.g. fork and then the parent becomes the reader and the child becomes the worker, or vice-versa), creating the appropriate queue beforehand and passing them to both. Never actually worked that much with multiprocessing so there could be other ways too.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yeah, unfortunately the reader will be kicked off by the web app.  I will look at queues.  Thank you sir!

Comment: @ChuckReed so when you say *"at the same time a reader process is kicked off"* - is it not actually the same time? Is the worker already running and the users of your website can open another "view" page to see the status at some time *after* the worker started? In such case it's a little bit trickier, but you could still achieve it how I suggested. Spawn both processes anyway, and accumulate results in the reader, then when the user requests the status flush the available results immediately for the user to see and continue polling from the queue.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli yes the later (and maybe I am just being stupid here).

Start - WebApp performs a PUT with some data
2) python prepares data received and spawns worker process, responds back to WebApp
2a) as the worker performs its task, it would write updates to queue/pipe/file/whatever
3) WebApp then makes AJAX call (poll) which would in essence be the short lived reader
4) reader checks queue/pipe/file/whatever and sends that status back to WebApp.
5) WebApp continues polling until the worker has completed wrote final status and exited.
6) Final status received by WebApp and is noted.

Comment: Well, you could also do this in a very simple way using signals. Set up a signal handler for e.g. `SIGUSR1` in the worker and then the reader just sends `kill(worker_pid, SIGUSR1)` and the worker dumps the status on stderr/stdout/file/pipe since it knows that when the signal is received the reader is there to read.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I suppose that is an option, though care would have to be given when the worker completes all of its tasks.  It would need to wait for the SIGUSR1 before it could exit, so that the reader gets the final status of complete.  If the Web App closes before or if there are network issues, you could end up with stranded process(es).  Would be nice to write and forget, knowing that the reader can pick it up whenever it pleases.